# Get MySQL data and store it to a PHP array based on the data array returned by another MySQL select operation

Tags: php, ios, mysql, foreach, while-loop

I am creating an iOS application and I am facing a difficulty with the web service portion, which is written in PHP. What I am trying to achieve is, sending push notification to the devices. I have completed that part. However, I need a mechanism to differentiate between notifications that has been delivered successfully to the phone and that haven't. I use a feedback web-service for this purpose and It is also working.  have a MySQL table with the following structure. Based on the status bit of each notification, I collect all the notifications corresponding to each device token, and make it into an array and send it to the device. Here is where I am facing difficulty.

I have two tables.

[image: THis is the notif_status table]

This table stores the notification ID, device token and status of the notification. By looking at this table, my script can determine whether the notification has been delivered to the particular device or not. My script collects all the notification IDs that has been undelivered to a particular device ID and uses the following apps_notif table to fetch the undelivered notifications. The table structure is as below.

[image: apps_notif table]

My PHP/MySQL script is as follows.

```
$fecthnotif=mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT notif_id FROM notif_status WHERE notif_status=0 AND dev_token='$device_token'") or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

$d2=array();     
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fecthnotif)) {  
    $d2[]=$row;

$json = json_encode($d2);

    $arr = json_decode( $json,true);
```

By this time, I get an array of undelivered notifications as JSON. The result is as follows.

[{"notif_id":"124"},{"notif_id":"129"}]

Now, I loop though the results as follows.

```
foreach($arr as $item) { //foreach element in $arr
    $uses= $item['notif_id']; }
```

What I am trying to achieve is to take each notif_id from the above result, fetch allthe notification data from the apss-Notif table, make it a single JSON object and return that payload to the app.So that JSON should have all the notification data of all the notifications that were undelivered at the first place.

Inside the foreach loop, I wrote a query loop to store all the pending notifications to array, but it isnt working.

```
$d=array();

foreach($arr as $item) { //foreach element in $arr
    $uses= $item['notif_id']; //etc
    //echo $uses;
    $sendnotif=mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM apps_notif WHERE notif_id='$uses'") or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sendnotif)) {  
    $d[]=$row;
    $i++;
    }
}
```

Edit: Basically, what I am trying to achieve is to return rows from the apps_notif table that match the criteria, notif_status=0 (from table notif_status) and dev_token="qwerty" (from apps_notif table)

I can see that two rows are eligible.

Comment: You could use JOINS to get data from 2 table instead of getting data from notif_status table first and then fetching the data apps_notif table like ``SEELCT a.* from apps_notif a JOIN notif_status b ON b.notif_id = a.notif_id WHERE b.notif_status=0 AND b.dev_token='$device_token'``

Comment: Could you please show me how to do it in php? with the code above? I am still confused about the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope it helps

```
SELECT b.* 
FROM notif_status a 
INNER JOIN apps_notif b ON a.notif_id = b.notif_id 
WHERE notif_status = 0 
  AND dev_token = '$device_token';
```

using sub queries,

```
SELECT * 
FROM app_notify 
WHERE notify_id IN (SELECT notif_id 
                    FROM notif_status 
                    WHERE notif_status = 0 
                      AND dev_token = '$device_token') ;
```

See in your table. In table 1 you have `notify_id` but in `table 2` you have `date` having kind of similar values. Hence if u match `table1 notifyId` and `table2 notifyId` you will not get the desired output. First check the proper criteria how the table should be designed.

Comment: Could you please show me how to do it in php? with the code above? I am still confused about the loop.

Comment: Query Returns error 
#1052 - Column 'notif_id' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: From `a.notify_id` change it to `b.*`

Comment: i think your `notify_id` is not matching.

Comment: Please see the data in the databases. There are 2 eligible rows . With notification ID 124 and 129. So I need the rows corresponding to 124 and 129 from apps_notif

Comment: Do u have any kind of relationships between those two tables?

Comment: This is what I am trying to achieve. from table notif_status, select a device ID(here "qwerty") and select the notif_ids with notif_status=0 and device_toekn="qwerty"

it will return two notif_ids (124 and 129)

now select the entire row from apps_notif table where notif_id=124 and 129

Logically, two rows would be returned.

Comment: @shreys: Thanks a lot. I confused date field with notif_id. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below PHP code to get the details from 2 table and make JSON object. Not tested query as i don't have respective DB tables.

```
$query = "SELECT a.* from apps_notif a JOIN notif_status b ON b.notif_id = a.notif_id WHERE b.notif_status=0 AND b.dev_token='$device_token'";
$res = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query);
$d = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
     $d[] = $row;
}
$json = json_encode($d);
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: When I print the JSON with echo, it just prints something like 

[]

Comment: May be query is not returning data. Check the query by printing it and copy the same then execute it in PhpMyadmin. See if your getting results are not.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SEELCT a.* from apps_notif a JOIN notif_status b ON b.notif_id = a.notif_id WHER' at line 1

Comment: its basic thing `select` not `seelct`

Comment: I corrected it. But it is still returning an empty row. It shouldn't because there are 3 rows that meets the criteria in which dev_token= 'qwerty' and notif_status=0

Comment: Can you share query output and what error you getting when run the query??

Comment: Query returning 0 rows.

Comment: please post the query with values in where clause that you trying to run ??